# biblatex / imakeidx – Avoid \citetitle entries to appear in index

Tags: biblatex, indexing, imakeidx, biblatex-philosophy

I use `biblatex` with Biber backend together with `imakeidx` to index my thesis. In the main text, I use `\citetitle` to reference names of books or articles. These get automatically added to the index. I would like to avoid that. Is there a way to keep `biblatex` or `imakeidx` from adding these entries to the index?

Here is a MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{lewis1979a,
    Author = {David Lewis},
    Journal = {Philosophical Review},
    Number = {4},
    Pages = {513--543},
    Title = {Attitudes \emph{De Dicto} and \emph{De Se}},
    Volume = {88},
    Year = {1979},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-classic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s latex.ist]

\begin{document}
As described by in Lewis's \citetitle{lewis1979a}, blabla.\index{Some Entry}

\printbibliography
\printindex

\end{document}
```

The output in the index:

[image: Output of MWE]

Comment: Depending on your needs `biblatex-fiwi` might fit the bill. It allows to turn on/off the indexing of titles independently. That means, you can index authors without titles (there's more fine grained control beyond that. You can, for example, index titles as subentries of author names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason `biblatex-philsophy`'s `\citetitle` command does not check for `\ifciteindex`, but always indexes the title. Use the following definition where we added the check back in

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex{\indexfield{indextitle}}{}%<--- the check is new
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex{\indexfield{indextitle}}{}%<--- the check is new
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{title}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```